# how do i make this unity project move my mouse with low sensitivity only left or right?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirstPersonMouseMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       Camera mycam = GetComponent<Camera>();
          
         transform.LookAt(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, mycam.nearClipPlane)), Vector3.up);
 float sensitivity = 0.5f;
 Vector3 vp = mycam.ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, mycam.nearClipPlane));
 vp.x -= 0.5f;
 vp.y -= 0.5f;
 vp.x *= sensitivity;
 vp.y *= sensitivity;
 vp.x += 0.5f;
 vp.y += 0.5f;
 Vector3 sp = mycam.ViewportToScreenPoint(vp);
 
 Vector3 v = mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(sp);  
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
          Camera mycam = GetComponent<Camera>();
         transform.LookAt(mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, mycam.nearClipPlane)), Vector3.up);
 float sensitivity = 0.5f;
 Vector3 vp = mycam.ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, mycam.nearClipPlane));
 vp.x -= 0.5f;
 vp.y -= 0.5f;
 vp.x *= sensitivity;
 vp.y *= sensitivity;
 vp.x += 0.5f;
 vp.y += 0.5f;
 Vector3 sp = mycam.ViewportToScreenPoint(vp);
 
 Vector3 v = mycam.ScreenToWorldPoint(sp); 
    }
}
```

i dont know why it doesnt work and it wont show any errors please help me im a beginner and i dont know what to do
S
S
SS
S
S
S
SS
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSSSdeykrtx5tjyrstrejstrje
terjterjterjtrej
retjtjretrejtrejtejr

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly lock the cursor to a single axis, because it's controlled by your OS. I think you could do it if you'd create a custom cursor inside Unity. But in case you're trying to clamp camera rotation you can use Mathf.Clamp ([Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)).